# C: String points to nonsense after assigning new pointer in function even though the address is correct

Tags: c, esp32

I need to call a function in a header file from my main file that reads a file from SPIFFS (in this code I just make up that information for more clarity) and assigns the given pointer to that file in memory. However when I do it as shown below the string behind its pointer returns nonsense when refered to in the main code, even though the pointer address is correct. Any ideas? I'm developing on ESP-IDF, but this should be a general C problem.

**Main**

```
void app_main()
{
    //...
    char* buffer;
    ESP_LOGI("TESTING", "buffer address in main: %d", *buffer);
    getPage(&buffer, "abc");

    ESP_LOGI("TESTING", "buffer address in main after getpage: %d", *buffer);
    ESP_LOGI("TESTING", "buffer in main after getpage is:%s", buffer);
    ESP_LOGI("TESTING", "buffer length in main after getpage is:%d", sizeof(buffer));
    //...

}
```

**Header File**

```
#include <esp_system.h>
#include<string.h>

esp_err_t getPage(char** buffer, char* path) 
{
    if(!*buffer){
        return ESP_ERR_INVALID_ARG;
    }

    if(strcmp(path, "abc") == 0)
    {
        char teststring[] = "This is my string that represents the buffer for my file.";
        ESP_LOGI("TESTING", "Address teststring: %d", *teststring);
        *buffer = &teststring;
        ESP_LOGI("TESTING", "buffer in function is:%s   address:%d", *buffer, **buffer);
    }

    return ESP_OK;
}
```

**Console output**

```
I (4649) TESTING: buffer address in main: 99
I (4659) TESTING: Address teststring: 84
I (4659) TESTING: buffer in function is:This is my string that represents the buffer for my file.   
address:84
I (4669) TESTING: buffer address in main after getpage: 84
I (4679) TESTING: buffer in main after getpage is:)@f?X?%@? f?
I (4679) TESTING: buffer length in main after getpage is:4
```

Comment: You're dereferencing your pointers.

Comment: Turn on all warnings.

Comment: Just to be sure, what do you think `*buffer` is in those log calls?

Comment: Welcome to SO. How long do you expect `char teststring[];` to live after you return from the function? Hint: Not very long. You should recapture your C text book about scopes and lifetime of variables.

Comment: Not related to the problem but you should never ever put function definitions into a header file.

Comment: `*teststring` does not represent an address but evaluates to a `char`.

Comment: To print a pointer, "%p" is the format to use.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! As you might have noticed I haven't fully grasped yet the concept of pointers but I'm getting there. Based off your comments and some more research I drew the following conclusions:
1. Header files are not made for function definitions but only for function declaration
2. C has a stack as well. Memory will be overwritte after variable is out of scope. That caused the inital truncation followed by gibberish after I made some changes. In order to fix that, I will need to make teststring static. I thought that assigning a pointer from above would preserve it.

Comment: 3. since my teststring will be a read file later on I will need to allocate memory dynamically and will also have to deal with garbage myself to avoid memoryleak. 
This leads me to the following questions:
After having added static to teststring it seems to work fine. Would this code be good practise to outsource loading a file? 
Thanks